# Можно ли в PL\SQL в IF для проверки вставить Select?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Я хочу в проверку условия вставить SELECT который возвращает 1 ячейку со словом "сайт" и проверить, что там именно "сайт" и выполнить код если оно истинно. В примере ниже оно так не работает. (Работаю в Pl\SQL Developer 8.0)

```
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT type
       FROM table1
       WHERE Partner_name = 'MTS') = 'сайт' THEN
   ....
   ....
  ELSE
   ....
   ....
  END IF;
END;
```

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает оно только если результат Селекта сначала положить в переменную, а её уже проверять в условии(как в примере ниже), но мне в коде куда одобнее было бы, если можно было просто вставлять селект в условие для проверки. Возможно ли это сделать с селектом?

```
DECLARE
  marketing varchar2(10);
BEGIN
SELECT type
   INTO marketing
   FROM table1
   WHERE Partner_name = 'MTS'
  IF marketing = 'сайт' THEN
   ....
   ....
  ELSE
   ....
   ....
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите в тэгах конкретную СУБД, так как IF везде работает по-разному

Comment: Нельзя.........

Comment: А есть какая нибудь альтернатива? или городить теперь кучу переменных и их потом проверять?

Comment: "В примере ниже оно так не работает", а как оно себя ведёт? Синтаксическая ошибка или условие не выполняется?

Comment: ORA-06550 - и ругается на то место где начинается SELECT после IF

Comment: Обычно после ORA-06550 и указания строки/столбца следующей строкой идёт пояснение к ошибке

Comment: Добавил скрин с ошибкой выше. Как я понимаю SELECT возвращает ячейку с содержимым, будь то число там или слово какое то, но IF видимо не может это сравнивать по условию с чем либо, по этому и выдаёт ошибку и пишет что так нельзя делать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вроде бы именно для этого существует `EXISTS`:

```
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM table1
       WHERE Partner_name = 'MTS' AND type = 'сайт')
  BEGIN
   ....
   ....
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
   ....
   ....
  END;
END;
```

Я так то в `SQL` не силён, возможно в вашем конкретном диалекте это пишется по-другому.

Comment: так нельзя сделать, ORACLE ругается. Да и данный метод не решит проблему